# Find $\det(C_n)$ where $c_{ij} = 1$ unless $i-j=\pm 1$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Find $\det(C_n)$ where $c_{ij} = 1$ unless $i-j=\pm 1$.

The original problem from the quiz,

> Let $C_n$ be the $n$ by $n$ matrix whose entries are all ones, except for zeros directly below and above the main diagonal; for example,
>   $$
> C_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Find $\det(C_n)$

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: It appears $\det C_{n+1}$ is given by http://oeis.org/A166445.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply row operations.  $C_5$, for example, has the same determinant as
$$
\pmatrix{
1 &0 &1&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&-1&0 \\
1&1&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&1
}
$$

Comment: But I fail to see how this can lead to recurrence or a general form.